# In python Im trying to parse a string where the element and the index plus one returns the desired index

Tags: python, string, list, decode

Hers is my code challenge and my code. I'm stuck, not sure why its not working properly

-write a function named plaintext that takes a single parameter of a string encoded in this format: before each character of the message, add a digit and a series of other characters. the digit should correspond to the number of characters that will precede the message's actual, meaningful character. it should return the decoded word in string form

```
"""  my pseudocode:
    #convert string to a list
    #enumerate list
    #parse string where the element and the index plus one returns the desired index
    #return decoded message of desired indexes  """

encoded_message = "0h2ake1zy"
#encoded_message ="2xwz"
#encoded_message = "0u2zyi2467"

def plaintext(string):
    while(True):
        #encoded_message = raw_input("enter encoded message:")
        for index, character in enumerate(list(encoded_message)):
            character = int(character)
            decoded_msg = index + character + 1
        print decoded_msg
```

Comment: Any advance on *"not working properly"*?

Comment: People here will usually downvote questions that look too much like homework. First, ask yourself why the while(True) loop. That's making your code loop forever.

Comment: I used the while loop because when I just used the for loop it wouldn't iterate past the first letter to decode.  Now when it iterates through the string it returns  a value error on the line character = int(character)

Comment: not homework just trying to keep learning python by completing some exercises for beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some hints.

First decide what looping construct you want to use. Python offers choices: iterate over individual characters, loop over the indices of the characters, while loop. You certainly don't want both a while and a for loop.

You're going to be processing the string in groups, "0h", then "2ake", then "1zy" to take your first example string. What is the condition that will cause you to exit the loop?

Now, look at your line `decoded_msg = index + character + 1`. To construct the decoded string, you want to index into the string itself, based on the digit's value. So, this line should contain something like, `encoded_message[x]` for some x, that you have to figure out using the digit.

Also, you'll want to accumulate characters as you go along. So you'll need to begin the loop with an empty result string `decoded_msg=""` and add a character to it `decoded_msg += ...` for each iteration of the loop.

I hope this helps a little more than just giving the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go iterate over the string's characters, and in each iteration skip the specified number of characters and take the following one:

```
def plaintext(s):
    res = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        # Skip the number of chars specified
        i += int(s[i])

        # Take the letter after them
        i += 1
        res += s[i]

        # Move on to the next position
        i += 1

    return res
```

Comment: this solution has the same problem I initially had, it stops after the first position, and does not actually iterate through the string.  Thank you though

Comment: @Mar Did you try running it? It correctly produces "hey" from your encoded example of "0h2ake1zy".

Comment: when I ran it it just returned h